# How to use backbone.js and jquery cloning to dynamically add and delete divs while making sure they display when back posting?

Tags: django, api, backbone.js

I have been struggling with this because I am new to backbone.js and am having difficulty creating this functionality. I have seen the examples such as todo.js on the backbone.js site which is similar, however I dont have the chance to test back posting with that. I was wondering if someone could give me a good idea of how to do this. I am using django with mongodb storage. All together I am struggling with:

1) Creating a rest api for backbone to use for storing in the db
2) Displaying the divs that I cloned to show up when I back post to the page.

Answer (score 0):

For creating a rest api, I recommend checking out these two packages:

https://github.com/toastdriven/django-tastypie

http://django-rest-framework.org/

As far as updating the view after a post, I don't know if I get exactly what the problem is, but [here](http://coenraets.org/blog/2011/12/backbone-js-wine-cellar-tutorial-part-3-deep-linking-and-application-states/) is the third part of a good tutorial.  The third part includes the full code.  The WineListView illustrates how a list is updated when the model collection changes.